# Can the Html Input Attribute Autocomplete be used in Jquery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

As my title states, I am hoping somebody can confirm for me if the HTML input attribute Autocomplete works in Jquery Mobile 1.4.5 ?

I am just wanting the basic email and telephone etc to pre-populate with previously entered data.

I have searched the net and Stack Overflow for an answer but just can not find one. The support documentation for JQM is not helping me either.

Whilst searching for answers I have seen so many links for autocomplete plugins and widgets for Jquery etc and this is making me thing it is not supported natively, but most of these offer pre-populated lists or set lists.

An example of how I was hoping to get away with it, which unfortunately does not work.

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
<label for="mobile-number-alerts1">Mobile number for SMS alerts:</label>
<input type="tel" id="mobile-number-alerts1" value="" data-clear-btn="true"
autocomplete="on">
</div>

<div class="ui-field-contain">
<label for="email-notifcation1">Email address for notifications:</label>
<input type="email" id="email-notifcation1" value="" data-clear-btn="true"
autocomplete="on">
</div>
```

If anybody could just confirm if it should work or not that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this question earned me tumbleweed, I have not been able to use the standard html autocomplete function with in Jquery Mobile 1.4.5 so I can only assume that it is not supported.